# Jupyter Notebook Installation

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am trying to install jupyter notebook in miniconda but it is giving me error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDIcd.png)

I am new to python and jupytr. I tried to install jupyter notebook in miniconda but it is giving me error about python version.

Comment: installing jupyter notebook uses the command `conda install notebook` not `conda install jupyter`

Comment: tried the command conda install notebook but still giving the same error

Comment: I would recommend you to create a new conda environment with a recent version of python, then install notebook in your new environment. You seem to be mixing venv with conda (and using mamba instead of miniconda) ... I suppose it should work but not sure. Don't mean to say it's bad, but I just don't do that. If you have conda, you can use conda to create and manage environments as well as to work with different versions of python.

Comment: Looks like you need Python 3.12 installed. Is it?